# Adding an XML wrapper to a php SOAP complex datatype

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

I am currently using the following in my nusoap server file:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'member',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'ID' => array('MemberInfo' => 'ID', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
        'FIRST_NAME' => array('MemberInfo' => 'FIRST_NAME', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'LAST_NAME' => array('MemberInfo' => 'LAST_NAME', 'type' => 'xsd:string')
)
```

Which returns:

```
<ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ID>
<FIRST_NAME xsi:type="xsd:string">John</FIRST_NAME>
<LAST_NAME xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe</LAST_NAME>
```

How can I modify this to receive the following output:

```
<ID xsi:type="xsd:int">1</ID>
<NAME>
            <FIRST_NAME xsi:type="xsd:string">John</FIRST_NAME>
            <LAST_NAME xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe</LAST_NAME>
</NAME>
```

Comment: Have you tried `'NAME' => array('FIRST_NAME' => ..., 'LAST_NAME' => ...)` ?

Comment: I have, the result is that neither First nor Last name gets returned.

Comment: From where you are getting _(1, John, Doe)_?

Comment: The values come from an array built in a php function called by my web service method. e.g. $my_array = array ('ID' => $row['ID'], FIRST_NAME' => $row['NAME'].... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the way to accomplish this was to include a single entry in my response datatype with an array for the wrapper:

```
'ID' => array('MemberInfo' => 'ID', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),    
'NAME' => array('NAME' => array('NAME', 'type' => 'xsd:string'))
```

And then of course store that name info in a sub array

```
return array (    
'ID' =>  $user_info->ID,
'NAME' => array(                            
        'FIRST_NAME' => $user_info->first_name,
        'LAST_NAME' => $user_info->last_name,
    )
)
```